# Cuál es la diferencia entre React-Router y React-Router-Dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Cuál es la diferencia entre React-Router vs React-Router-Dom ... Ambos tienen Route, Link, etc. ¿Cuándo usar cada uno?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/quick-start) se utiliza para proyectos que **no** hacen uso del [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Referencia_DOM_de_Gecko/Introducci%C3%B3n). Un ejemplo de esto son aplicaciones nativas que utilizamos en dispositivos móviles.

- Por ejemplo, una aplicación creada con [React Native](http://reactnative.dev/).

[React Router DOM](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) se utiliza para la aplicaciones web que hacen uso del DOM (interfaz de programación para documentos HTML).

- Por ejemplo, una aplicación creada con [React](https://reactjs.org/)

Resumiendo: si estás desarrollando aplicaciones web, vas a utilizar React Router DOM. Si en cambio estás desarrollando aplicaciones nativas, vas a hacer uso de React Router.